# removing of paragraph indent with \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} and \usepackage{parskip} does not work

Tags: latex

I try to get rid of all automatic indentions in my document. Unfortunately, neither \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} nor \usepackage{parskip} do their job.

These are all packages I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, left=2.0cm, right=5.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this article: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX#The_fundamentals:_parameter_commands_and_examples, you should add the command `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` not in the preamble, but after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: The fact that overleaf uses `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` after `\begin{document}` does not mean that it should not be used in the preamble, both works. The example in the linked article uses it within the document to change the value during the document to show a couple of different applications.